# How do I populate the form fields in react from my state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an edit form that is working except I can't figure out how to pre-populate the fields so that when I navigate to it according to its params the user can see the current value of each field before overriding it?

P.S. It may look like a duplicate from my other post but it's a separate issue

```
import React from 'react'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useParams } from "react-router";

const EditTask = () => {
  const api ="http://localhost:5000"

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]) 
  const [task, setTask] = useState([]) 
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  const [day, setDay] = useState('')
  const [reminder, setReminder] = useState(false)
  const params  = useParams();

  const fetchTask = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${api}/tasks/${params.id}`, {
      method: "GET"
    })
    const data = await res.json()
    return data
  }

  //Get Request
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTask = async () => {
      const tasksFromServer = await fetchTask()
      setTask(tasksFromServer)
      console.log("tasksFromServer", tasksFromServer);
    }
    getTask()
  },[])


  //Update request
  const updateData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    await fetchTask(task.id)
    const updateTask = {
      ...task, 
      reminder: reminder,
      text: text,
      day: day
    }
    console.log("updateTask", updateTask)

    await fetch(`${api}/tasks/${task.id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(updateTask)          
    })

    setTasks(
      tasks.map((task) => 
        task.id === params.id 
        ? {...task, updateTask}
        : task
      )
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <header className='header'>
        <h1>Edit</h1>
        <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary">Go Back</Link>
      </header>
      <form className="add-form" onSubmit={updateData}>            
        <div className="form-control">
          <label>Task</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add Task" value={text} onChange={(e)=> setText(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label>Day & Time</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add Day & Time"  value={day} onChange={(e)=> setDay(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control form-control-check">
          <label>Set Reminder</label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={reminder} value={reminder} onChange={(e)=> setReminder(e.currentTarget.checked)}/>
        </div>
        <input className="btn btn-block" type="submit" value="Save Task" />
      </form>
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default EditTask
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you get your params before defining your useState and set those as initial values if available?

**Update:**

Something like this,

```
const params  = useParams();
const [text, setText] = useState(params.text??'');
```

Assuming you get a `text` property from your `params`. If not set a default value. Params are part of your URL and it's not clear from your question that you have your initial data coming from URL parts or as a query string. So I assumed you have a URL and you are getting some values as part of your URL.

**Update 2:**

Since you are getting the data you need as part of the result of the API, just set the state for those values.

```
//Get Request
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTask = async () => {
      const tasksFromServer = await fetchTask()
// Set state here so you will override the default values..
      setTask(tasksFromServer)
      setText(tasksFromServer.text);
       setDay(tasksFromServer.day);
       setReminder(tasksFromServer.reminder);

      console.log("tasksFromServer", tasksFromServer);
    }
    getTask()
  },[])
```

Comment: `const [text, setText] = useState(task.text)` like this? It didn't work

Comment: I have updated my answer. Assuming you have some values in `params` which you are getting from your route.

Comment: The only params I'm poassing is the id. The text, day, and reminder are states. IN other words `localhost:3000/tasks/sometext` doesn't exist. The only param I am using is `:id`

Comment: So where is the data that you want to pre-populate?

Comment: If it's coming as part of `fetchTask` then set state with that data, like you are doing `setTask(tasksFromServer)`

Comment: IT's in the api link shown in the fetch and mapped to the task state. So if I console log "task" I get the object with the text property and its value as well as the day and reminder. IN fact, if I console log task.text, I get the exact value. But it's not showing in the input field

Comment: Check my update. You need to set the state for those values.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! I understand what you did. Makes sense!

Comment: Great!!. I don't know whether you need `setTask(tasksFromServer) ` as I can't see it used anywhere. You can adjust the code as you need. Happy coding..

Comment: I need it or the task object wont update the id. But I do have the dependencies complaining that I need to add fetchTask as a dependency, and when I add it it creates more errors. Should I just ignore that? Sorry. I know you already answered the initial question

Comment: Those are warnings. You can ignore or add that function as a dependancy. Every time your component renders there will be a new instance of that function so it will trigger useeffect. Thats why we use useCallback with those dependant functions. You may read about those before using.